# Access .Net Webservice running with local Visual Studio in LAN

Tags: .net, visual-studio, web-services

I wrote a .Net Webservice and started it on my PC with Visual Studio. Accessing it locally with http://localhost:28250/MyService.asmx works just fine! However, I would now like to call it also from another PC that is in the same LAN. For that I disabled the firwall and entered a port permission into the router. Unfortunatelly though it doesn't work...It only indicates that the page can not be found :(

Could you please help me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should publish your webservice on IIS for this.
[This link](http://support.discountasp.net/KB/a792/how-do-i-deploy-visual-studio-2010-web-application.aspx) should drive you in the right direction.

Comment: Thank you Marco, that helped me a lot. Now I installed the IIS locally and my webservice is running in there. Also I can now call it from other devices in the same network.

Comment: Now I realized though that I need it to be publicly available. So I used a dynamic DNS service to make my laptop available over internet. Now calling myAssignedAddress.no-ip.org/MyService.asmx however leads to the same problem. Maybe you or someone else could help with this issue? Thanks again!

Comment: @user1192475: Use [DynDns](http://www.dyndns.org): it's free and gives you the opportunity to have a third level name (something.dyndns.org); then using an app (free, downloadable from site) you can update your ip, having name-ip pair always valid

Comment: @user1192475: also remember you should [accept an answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) that solved or helped to solve your problem

Comment: @user1192475: sorry, what do you mean with *"leads to the same problem"*?

Comment: Actually No-Ip does the same, updating my external IP on myChosenAddress.no-ip.org DynDNS unfortunatelly doesn't seem to be free anymore (only trial) so I guess No-IP is just fine. But calling myChosenAddress.no-ip.org/MyService.asmx again leads to the page not being able to load. Maybe it has to do with the fact that the Webaddress references to my external IP (the one of my internet router) and not to the specific laotop that is integrated in the network behind it?

Comment: @user1192475: IIS should respond on "public" port; if not you have to map external port to internal one inside your router (e.g. public 80TCP -> your IIS IP:80TCP)